bash function to monitor resources
I've written the following fn to monitor my cpu usage:
cpu_info() {
        local bg \
                cpu_usage=$(top -b -n1 | awk '/Cpu\(s\)/ {print $2 + $4}' | awk '{printf "%.0f\n", $1}')

        if (( cpu_usage > 75 )); then
            bg='\[\e[41m\]'
        elif (( cpu_usage > 50 )); then
            bg='\[\e[43m\]'
        else
            bg='\]\e[42m\]'
        fi

                    
        echo -n "CPU" $bg$(top -b -n1 | awk '/Cpu\(s\)/ {print $2 + $4 "%"}')$x
}

which ive added to my $PROMPT_COMMAND
my question (besides how do i improve it, as I'm new to Bash) is, is it possible to monitor the output of top like so:
top | grep "Cpu(s)" | cut -d: -f2 | cut -d, -f1

or something similar? I've tried the above and it weirdly runs in the background or something because when I quit with (q) it shows the output I need but it's blank until then
My above code is just a snapshot so running new commands in my terminal will provide me with a fresh snapshot but if I havent touched the terminal in a while, it'll show the info that was there since last interaction
I'm looking to make a live top snippet to add to my $PROMPT_COMMAND

I know I can print out snapshots, I'm curious if I can view specific live output from top, so instead of every proc, just the first 5 lines for example, but live, not a snapshot
